# Por que objetos diferentes da mesma classe podem acessar campos privados um do outro?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes, segurança, visibilidade

Hoje enquanto estava fazendo um curso no Udacity (Intro to Java Programming) pensei sobre isso no exercício Update the `class Person` (lição 3 29/45).

Na modelagem orientada a objetos temos o conceito de encapsulamento (esconder implementação) que não tem relação direta com proteção, mas observando um dos propósitos da POO que é fornecer uma modelagem mais próxima da organização no mundo real, por que João pode ler os "pensamentos" de Maria e não perguntar a ela?

### Exemplo de classe

```
class Pessoa {
    // Pensamentos sao privados
    private List<String> pensamentos;
    
    public void lePensamentos(Pessoa outraPessoa) {
         // Por que uma pessoa pode ler os pensamentos de outra pessoa?
         System.out.println(outraPessoa.pensamentos);
    }
}
```

### Exemplo de acesso "indevido" aos pensamentos de outro objeto

```
Pessoa joao = new Pessoa();
Pessoa maria = new Pessoa();

//João é um objeto em um mundo virtual que representa uma pessoa e seu comportamento deve ser como esperado no mundo real!
//João está curioso para saber o que Maria está pensando então ele chama um método para acabar com sua curiosidade
maria.fazPergunta("O que você está pensando Maria?");

//João percebe que ela não quis responder e achou uma solução! Acessar diretamente seus pensamentos (superpoderes!)
joao.lePensamentos(maria); // isso funciona!
```

**A linguagem Java oferece algum recurso de proteção quanto a isso?** Em Java temos o recurso de isolar partes da memória por questões de segurança? (Essa pergunta fica apenas para reflexão ou comentário extra)

### Esclarecimentos

1. O exemplo demonstra situações em que `joão` (instância) acessa atributos/campos de Maria que deveriam ser particulares somente dela.
2. A palavra "privado" está mais em outro contexto do que *access modifiers* em Java, aqui eu coloco esta palavra como se fosse "algo particular" que só a instância deveria ter acesso direto (pense em outros atributos também como um atributo que guarda a "senha" de alguém, etc.).

Por isso fiz a pergunta se em Java temos o recurso de isolar partes da memória por questões de segurança.

Comment: Não entendi a ligação do seu raciocinio com o código informado. Se pensamentos for público, ele será acessivel mesmo, se for privado, essa chamada irá dar erro.

Comment: @diegofm o código foi só uma brincadeira, pense na pergunta: Por que instâncias de uma classe podem acessar campos privados uma da outra?

Comment: Não podem, campo privado é acessível apenas por aquela instancia. Não existe compartilhamento de métodos privados, nem se houver herança entre classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604431/why-can-an-instance-of-a-class-access-private-fields-of-another-instance-of-its

Comment: @diegofm, não podem? =)

Comment: Ainda não liguei o raciocinio da pergunta ao código. Lá o código mostra uma classe acessar seu próprio membro privado, seu código está fazendo algo completamente diferente. Se pensamentos for privado, da forma como você está fazendo neste código, não vai nem compilar.

Comment: leia com mais calma o exemplo @diegofm, veja "foo.secret = 100;" ele usou "foo" que é uma outra instância de Foo.

Comment: Lá sim, aqui não. Mas espere que alguém que talvez consiga entender possa te responder. Eu realmente não entendi código com a dúvida.

Comment: Acho que a confusão é que você apenas falou de João, mas em nenhum momento você utiliza ele, a não ser nos comentários.

Comment: Eu acho que já vi esse problema de João e Maria misturando pensamentos no site, mas não lembro onde foi. Vou dar uma pesquisada, e se achar o link para a postagem eu colo aqui.

Comment: @Randrade, achei que era o suficiente os comentários. O erro foi meu, deveria ter deixado mais claro que João é quem estava acessando Maria. Pensei que pelo fato de ter somente 2 objetos não haveria a necessidade, mas tudo bem! Vivendo e aprendendo! Obrigado pelos comentários!

Comment: Não tem problema. Apenas falei pois quanto mais claro for em sua pergunta, maior será a chance de conseguir respostas de boa qualidade.

Comment: @guiwp Tomei a liberdade de deixar o seu título um pouco mais claro. Do jeito que estava, estava induzindo ao erro de entendimento que ocorreu aqui.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida, muito obrigado

Comment: guiwp, eu acho que você poderia alterar seu exemplo para ficar mais didático. Se seu exemplo incluísse um método `void leMente(Pessoa outraPessoa) { System.out.println(outraPessoa.pensamentos); }` e uma chamada `joao.leMente(maria);` não restaria espaço para confusão.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly vc deu uma boa sugestão, fique à vontade para modificar! =)

Comment: guiwp, feito. Dê uma olhada para ver se você concorda com as edições.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O exemplo da pergunta não mostra o que foi perguntado.

## TL;DR

A resposta simples para a pergunta é porque os *designers* da linguagem quiseram assim e foi [especificado isso](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1). C++ fez assim, C# também.

## Justificativa

Uma justificativa para optarem por isso é que o compilador está analisando um código que não está executando. Ele não fica olhando por objetos, ele só olha o que está ali na classe. Ele não tem como garantir que o objeto que está ali é um objeto diferente do atual. Pode ser o atual.

Claro que poderia adotar uma convenção que se o objeto não vier pelo parâmetro implícito `this`, que todo método de instância tem, então ele deveria ser considerado um objeto diferente do atual. Mas isso complicaria alguns padrões de uso. O que está recebendo pode nem ser o objeto desta classe concretamente, mas sim uma instância de uma derivada.

## Um bom exemplo

Como faria um `equals()` entre dois objetos da mesma classe, um deles é o parâmetro `this` implícito e outro poderia ser um parâmetro explícito `that`? É comum que o método de igualdade acesse membros privados para verificar a igualdade.

```
public boolean equals(Pessoa that) {
    return this.nome.equals(that.nome); //considero que nome é privado
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Private.java).

Aí você deve se perguntar qual seria o ganho de bloquear isso. O membro privado não é um mecanismo de proteção de acesso a dados. É só uma forma para facilitar que o código não veja membros que dependem de detalhe de implementação, não é algo que vá dar segurança.

## Encapsulamento

Não gosto dessa definição dada na pergunta. Pra mim, pelo que entendi em tudo o que estudei, o encapsulamento é colocar tudo em uma única cápsula, tudo que se refere àquilo como uma coisa só. Isso acaba criando uma abstração, mas esconder o detalhe de implementação em si é outra coisa. Então vou falar mais da abstração do que o encapsulamento aqui, embora eles estejam bem relacionados (poderia falar em *information hiding*).

Se o detalhe de implementação mudar foi a própria classe que mudou. Todo o código da classe deveria estar ciente da mudança. O mecanismo não quer salvar o programador de fazer qualquer mudança na classe inadvertidamente, sob pena de tornar o código muito rígido. Isso existe apenas para impedir acessos externos à classe dentro da normalidade. Esse acesso é interno.

É usado para encapsulamento, que se refere à classe e não ao objeto. Qualquer objeto desta classe é "confiável" do ponto de vista de código.

Claro que alguma linguagem pode dar a opção de restringir isso, afinal tem sua utilidade, como Scala faz (vide comentário do Anthony Accioly).

## Conclusão

Então entenda que *não é para proteger de acesso ao **objeto**, é para garantir a visibilidade interna na **classe***. Não é um mecanismo de segurança, é apenas conceitual. Lembre-se que qualquer objeto pode ser acessado de onde quiser por diversas técnicas, mais ou menos sofisticadas, que passam por cima do compilador, por exemplo com reflexão.

Comment: Sr @bigown, obrigado comentário. 1) O exemplo da pergunta não mostra o que foi perguntado. R: Era só para mostrar joão (uma instância) acessando campos de outra instância (maria). A parte comentada com "joão" era João acessando, espero ter ficado mais claro agora.

Comment: Eu trouxe a palavra "privada" para um outro contexto, não sei se você percebeu. Mas quem sabe eu possa deixar o texto mais claro da próxima vez! Alias vcs não leem meus pensamentos rsrs

Comment: Acho que essa confusão vem especialmente do mau-entendimento de que os modificadores de acesso têm alguma relação com segurança dos dados. Não é essa a intenção deles. A ideia é impedir que códigos clientes da sua classe dependam de detalhes internos de implementação da mesma ao ponto de te impedir de mudá-los no futuro. Se o código que está tentando acessar o atributo é seu próprio código (independente de quem o esteja rodando no momento), então está tudo sob seu controle.

Comment: @Pablo seu comentário reforça o que é encapsulamento, muito bom! estou aprendendo bastante. obrigado

Comment: +1 como gesto de humildade em perceber que tenho muito a aprender  =)

Comment: É por isso que [escopos em scala podem incluir qualificadores](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_access_modifiers.htm). `private[this]` faz exatamente o que você quer.

Comment: perfeito @AnthonyAccioly, acho q não vai demorar muito eu vou ter q aprender scala!

Answer (score 8):

Como você mesmo mencionou guiwp, baseado na resposta do SO em inglês neste link [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604431/why-can-an-instance-of-a-class-access-private-fields-of-another-instance-of-its):

O membro privado de uma classe tem como objetivo encapsulamento de código. Isto serve tanto para manter a organização como para impedir que agentes **externos** a classe modifiquem ela de maneira inesperada.

Como no exemplo (copiado para o trecho de código abaixo para facilitar) a classe manipula a uma instância dela própria. Isto não quebra a regra de encapsulamento que faz com que ela seja protegida de agentes externos, pois a classe tem conhecimento sobre como "lidar" com as informações contidas nela própria.

```
public class Foo {
  private int secret;
  public void bar(final Foo foo) {
    foo.secret = 100;
  }
}
```

Caso a situação fosse: `class Bar` tenta alterar membro privado de `Foo` um erro seria disparado.

Como `Foo` altera uma instância de `Foo` (uma instância da mesma classe) internamente o Java (assim como outras linguagens também fazem) entende como um comportamento normal.

Answer (score 6):

Porque a finalidade dos níveis de controle de acesso não é essa.

A ideia do encapsulamento é garantir que suas classes não possam sofrer interferências nocivas de outras classes.

Ou seja, se você projetou a classe X para solucionar o problema Y, você não vai querer que o seu vizinho projete uma classe Z que usa a sua classe X de uma forma totalmente inadequada e acabe quebrando com as premissas que embasam o seu funcionamento adequado. Com esse controle de acesso, fica bem mais fácil desenvolver código robusto, seguro, bem testável e mais a-prova-de-idiotas, graças ao encapsulamento.

A ideia é você expor às demais classes, que podem ter sido projetadas por pessoas diferentes, apenas as formas válidas e que fazem sentido de interagirem com ela. Para pegar um exemplo concreto bastante batido, imagine a classe `String`. Ela tem um campo privado do tipo `char[]` (no OpenJDK 8), e para que uma `String` possa ser usada de forma segura e que faça sentido, você não vai querer que a classe `Gambiarra123` que o sobrinho do seu vizinho inventou acabe bagunçando com as `String`s de todo o sistema por algum motivo idiota qualquer.

Desse conceito de expôr apenas o que pode ser utilizado e manipulado de forma sã pelas demais classes ou não, advém os níveis de visibilidade públicos e privados, que são os mais usados. Os níveis de visibilidade protegidos e de pacote do java (e o `friend` do C++) são casos intermediários para situações excepcionais específicas e que na prática se aplicam muito raramente.

Desta forma, com o controle de acesso público ou privado é possível separar-se qual parte da classe corresponde ao comportamento que é exposto ao mundo externo da parte que é apenas algum detalhe interno para que a sua implementação possa funcionar adequadamente e realizar aquilo que se propõe.

Agora vem a questão: Se você escreveu a classe X, então não tem lá muito sentido você proteger o código da classe X contra uso indevido de si própria, afinal de contas, trata-se do mesmo código, escrito pelas mesmas pessoas. E é por causa disso que as linguagens de programação em geral têm regras de controle de acesso baseadas em classes e não em instâncias. Não faz sentido ao código de uma classe querer restringir o controle de acesso para algo ainda mais restrito do que apenas si mesma.

Em suma, o controle de acesso é uma coisa que serve para organizar e proteger o código antes de este ser submetido ao compilador, e não os objetos em memória durante a execução. Instância é um conceito que só surge em uma outra etapa, quando o código já está executando, e nesta etapa o controle de acesso já não é mais necessário porque a etapa de compilação já passou.

No caso de isso permitir que "*uma pessoa acabe lendo a mente de outra pessoa*", para isso, o ideal seria trabalhar com interfaces, onde uma pessoa vê outras pessoas e sabe o que elas podem fazer, mas não pode ler os seus pensamentos. Cada pessoa tem os seus comportamentos específicos, que muitas vezes não são conhecidos em profundidade por outras pessoas. Agora, quando você trabalha com código da classe, você já tem todos os detalhes referentes ao comportamento e neste caso, se uma pessoa acaba por ler o pensamento da outra indevidamente, é porque trata-se de um erro de programação na classe `Pessoa`, e não de uma interferência nociva por parte de uma outra classe.

Por fim, há sim algumas linguagens que acabam implementando a restrição de acessos em termo de instâncias. O Scala tem o modificador `private[this]`. O Ruby interpreta o `private` dessa forma.

E ainda, a partir do Java 9, também há o conceito de encapsulamento no nível de módulos, e não apenas de classes. A lógica é a mesma. Dentro de um mesmo módulo, você pode acessar coisas internas daquele módulo pois é o mesmo código que deve ou deveria ter sido projetado de forma coesa pelas mesmas pessoas. No entanto, o acesso aos detalhes internos de um módulo é bloqueado aos demais módulos para evitar que o acesso indevido a partes internas do módulo acabem por comprometer o seu funcionamento.

Comment: Visto que falou que "linguagens de programação em geral", isso aqui é somente um adendo, uma curiosidade. Ruby é um exemplo de linguagem que o `private` aplica um controle de acesso baseado em instância.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura É porque Ruby não tem uma etapa de compilação bem definida e separada da execução, e por isso o controle de acesso é empurrado para o tempo de execução.

Comment: "Não faz sentido ao código de uma classe querer restringir o controle de acesso para algo ainda mais restrito do que apenas si mesma." Já imaginou comportamentos que só podem ser previstos em tempo de execução? imagina que eu tenho um algoritmo de IA que dá liberdade de objetos (Pessoas) inspecionar uns aos outros dentro de um mundo virtual afim de ganhar vantagem, seria interessante restringir acesso a certos membros em determinadas situações

Comment: @guiwp Para isso, o ideal seria trabalhar com interfaces, onde uma pessoa vê outras pessoa e sabe o que elas podem fazer, mas não pode ler os seus pensamentos. Cada pessoa tem os seus comportamentos específicos, que muitas vezes não são conhecidos em profundidade por outras pessoas. Agora, quando você trabalha com código da classe, você já tem todos os detalhes referentes ao comportamento e neste caso, se uma pessoa acaba por ler o pensamento da outra indevidamente, é porque trata-se de um erro de programação na classe `Pessoa`, e não de uma interferência nociva por parte de uma outra classe.

Comment: Acho que vale a pena dar uma revisitada aqui e colocar coisas de módulos do Java 9. O que acha, @VictorStafusa?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Feito. Embora para ser sincero, isso já foge um pouco ao escopo da pergunta, embora ainda assim seja uma informação complementar relevante.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, no seu exemplo, pelo que entendi, o que Maria esta pensando é o que Maria sabe, suas informações, seus atributos. Se tais atributos forem privados, para João saber o que Maria esta pensando é necessário sim perguntar para Maria. No caso o seu método de exemplo ".fazPergunta()" seria equivalente a um ".getPensamento" , ou seja, se os campos/atributos de uma classe estão privados é preciso sim enviar uma mensagem/perguntar para o outro objeto da mesma classe sobre determinado atributo. Logo, não é possível tais objetos "lerem os pensamentos" de outros objetos.

Comment: obrigado felipe, mas é justamente esse o problema! Na linguagem Java um objeto da classe Pessoa acessa livremente os pensamentos de outra pessoa! Não soube até o momento como tornar verdadeiramente particular um membro de uma classe a outras instâncias dessa mesma classe.

Comment: faz o teste você mesmo; crie as classes e modifique o membro "pensamento" um do outro